# How to keep the first appearing of each ID in the data frame

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like the one on the left, and I would like to add a new variable to show the unique ID. What should I do? Only the first appearing of the ID will be show in `UniqueID`

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c("Jerry", "Jerry", "Mary", "Tom"), Score = c(65, 
98, 88, 75)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `duplicated` to create a logical vector for `replace`ing the duplicates with `""` or `NA`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(UniqueID = replace(ID, duplicated(ID), ""))
```

Comment: Just curious, is it possible to do this using `group_by` ?

Comment: @Stataq if you need it by each 'ID', just add the `group_by(ID)` before the `mutate` or `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(UniqueID = replace(ID, -1, "")) %>% ungroup`

Comment: I am thinking  `group_by(ID) ` and then the first record of each group, UniqueID=ID. Not sure whether it is doable. 

Comment: @Stataq You can use `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(UniqueID = replace(ID, -1, "")) %>% ungroup` or `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(UniqueID = case_when(row_number() ==1 ~ ID, TRUE ~ ""))`

Answer (score 2):

```r
df$UniqueID <- ifelse(duplicated(df$ID), "", df$ID)
```

```r
  ID    Score UniqueID
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
1 Jerry    65 "Jerry" 
2 Jerry    98 ""      
3 Mary     88 "Mary"  
4 Tom      75 "Tom"
```